# Per-chapter bibliographies with global list at the end

Tags: biblatex

I would like to create a bibliography for each chapter. Each chapter needs to use a citation number from the global citation number.

for example

```
Chapter1
this is chapter1 \cite{A}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

chapter2
this is chapter2 \cite{B}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]


\printbibliography
```

the result should be

> **Chapter 1**
>
> this is chapter1[1]
>
> *ref*
>
> [1] AuthorA
>
> **Chapter 2**
>
> this is chapter2  [2]
>
> *ref*
>
> [2] AuthorB
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> [1] authorA
>
> [2] authorB

I don't need each chapter to reset the citation number.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily possible with `refsegment`s. The most convenient way to use them is probably by passing `segment=chapter,` to `biblatex` at loading time. Then `biblatex` will start a new `refsegment` for every `\chapter`. Per-chapter bibliographies are produced with

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment]
```

and only contain citations from the current `refsegment`/chapter. The complete bibliography is produced without a `segment` filter and prints all citations.

For a scheme like this you probably want to use `sorting=none, defernumbers=true,` to get continuous numbering of the references.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric,
  sorting=none, defernumbers=true,
  refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment]

\chapter{Ipsum}
Ipsum \autocite{nussbaum,geer}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment]


\printbibliography[title=Overall bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have a little problem.
I have some chapters it doesn't need to print bibliography.  For example If I have 4 chapters. Only chapter 3 doesn't need to create a bibliography but it have a citation in the chapter. Therefore, chapters 1,2 and 4 have a bibliography.

Comment: @PisitNakjai You can of course just leave out the `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment]` in chapter 3. But then citations that only occur in chapter 3 will only be listed in the global bibliography.

Comment: My problem is 
if I cited in chapter 3. The citation number will be index with the last number.
This is example

>Chapter 1

>this is chapter1[1]

>ref

>[1] AuthorA

>Chapter 2

>this is chapter2 [2]

>ref

>[2] AuthorB

>Chapter 3

>this is chapter3 [4]

>Chapter 4

>this is chapter4 [3]

>ref

>[3] AuthorD


>Bibliography

>[1] authorA  
>[2] authorB
>[4] authorC
>[3] authorD

In chapter 3, the citation index should be number 3.

Comment: @PisitNakjai Remove the option `defernumbers=true,`. If you don't see the desired effect after recompilation, remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and compile again.

Comment: Thank you. It works.